# How can I set timestamps accurately for midi events?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, coremidi, mikmidi

I am parsing a midi file and then sending midi events to connected synthesizer using [MIKMIDI](https://github.com/mixedinkey-opensource/MIKMIDI) but I am getting the events timestamps rounded to an integral second rather than more specific milliseconds. I need help calculating the time accurately. Thanks.
    // defined earlier
    class Note {
      var symbol:String
      var octave:Int
      var midiValue:Int
      var duration:Float
    }

```
let BPM:Double = 75
// Ode to joy simplified
var song:[Note] = [
  Note(symbol: "E", octave: 5),
  Note(symbol: "E", octave: 5),
  Note(symbol: "F", octave: 5),
  Note(symbol: "G", octave: 5),

  Note(symbol: "G", octave: 5),
  Note(symbol: "F", octave: 5),
  Note(symbol: "E", octave: 5),
  Note(symbol: "D", octave: 5),

  Note(symbol: "C", octave: 5),
  Note(symbol: "C", octave: 5),
  Note(symbol: "D", octave: 5),
  Note(symbol: "E", octave: 5),

  Note(symbol: "E", octave: 5, duration: 3/8),
  Note(symbol: "D", octave: 5, duration: 1/8),
  Note(symbol: "D", octave: 5, duration: 1/2)
]
let now = NSDate()
let totalDuration:Double = 0
for note:Note in song {
  let fullNoteValue:Double = (60000 / BPM) * 0.001 * 4
  let noteDuration:Double = fullNoteValue * Double(note.duration)
  let timestamp = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(noteDuration + totalDuration)
  MidiDevice.sharedInstance().playNoteOn(note.midiValue, withTimestamp: timestamp)
  totalDuration += noteDuration
}
```

MidiDevice playNoteOn definition

```
- (void)playNoteOn:(NSInteger)note withTimestamp:(MIDITimeStamp)timestamp {
  MIKMutableMIDINoteOnCommand *noteOn = [MIKMutableMIDINoteOnCommand commandForCommandType:MIKMIDICommandTypeNoteOn];
  noteOn.note = (NSUInteger) note;
  noteOn.velocity = 100;
  noteOn.timestamp = timestamp
  // noteOn.midiTimestamp = timestamp;

  NSMutableArray *destinations = [NSMutableArray array];

  for (MIKMIDIDevice *device in [[MIKMIDIDeviceManager sharedDeviceManager] availableDevices]) {
    for (MIKMIDIEntity *entity in [device.entities valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.destinations"]) {
      [destinations addObject:entity];
    }
  }

  //  NSArray *destinations = [self.device.entities valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.destinations"];
  if (![destinations count]) return;
  for (MIKMIDIDestinationEndpoint *destination in destinations) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if(![self.deviceManager sendCommands:@[noteOn] toEndpoint:destination error:&error]) {
      NSLog(@"Unable to send command %@ to endpoint %@: %@", noteOn, destination, error);
    }
  }
}
```

How do I change this timestamp to an accurate one I can send using MIDISend() or MIKMIDI?

Comment: Hi @matt I was going for concise but I guess my question was too ambiguous. Thanks.

Comment: You are still not showing real code. For example, the line `noteOn.timestamp = timestamp` lacks a semicolon, so it would not compile. Just copy your code and paste it into your question! Don't mess with it; simply show the actual code.

Answer (score 2):

You are using incompatible time measurements. First you say this:

```
let now = NSDate()
let timestamp = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(noteDuration + totalDuration)
```

But then you hand that to the midi device:

```
 MidiDevice.sharedInstance().playNoteOn(note.midiValue, withTimestamp: timestamp)
```

But the timestamp here, it turns out, is supposed to be a MIDITimeStamp:

```
(void)playNoteOn:(NSInteger)note withTimestamp:(MIDITimeStamp)timestamp {
```

A MIDITimeStamp is not an NSDate! MIDITimeStamp is based on `mach_absolute_time()`, a completely different kind of measure. An NSDate is measured as an NSTimeInterval, which is a Double counting seconds from some fixed reference date-time. Mach absolute time is a huge integer counting nanoseconds from when the computer was turned on!

So, to call this method successfully, you need to get rid of the NSDate and think in MIDI time.